# how to retrieve JSON object from the JSON array in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I am having the below JSON response. Inside this JSON I am having "result" as JSON array. From this array I want to retrieve and display the value of each instance name and corresponding status. How can I do that?

```
{
  "oradbInstance" : {
    "oraDBHost" : "",
    "oraDBPort" : "",
    "oraDBSid" : "",
    "oraDBPass" : "",
    "oraDBJdePass" : "",
    "oraDBStatus" : "",
    "oraDBDepComponent" : "",
    "oraSHARED" : false,
    "oraADF" : false,
    "oraOVR" : false,
    "oradbSchema" : {
      "oraPROD" : false,
      "oraPRIST" : false,
      "oraCRP" : false,
      "oraDEV" : false
    },
    "oradbDemoSchema" : {
      "oraPRODDEMO" : false,
      "oraPRISTDEMO" : false,
      "oraCRPDEMO" : false,
      "oraDEVDEMO" : false
    }
  },
  "result" : [ {
    "instanceName" : "ent6327",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "STOPPED"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "ent790",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "STOPPED"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "920_ENT_6017",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "ent7943",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "STOPPED"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "920_JAS_8082",
    "targetType" : "webserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "ENT6547",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "STOPPED"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "ent4563",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "STOPPED"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "ent6021",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "AIS_0005",
    "targetType" : "restserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "DEN00KNL_DEP_920",
    "targetType" : "depserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "wls1213",
    "targetType" : "owl_1212",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "HTML_8792",
    "targetType" : "webserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "home",
    "targetType" : "mgmtconsole",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "ent6060_Win",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "RTE_0004",
    "targetType" : "rteserver",
    "status" : "RUNNING"
  }, {
    "instanceName" : "ent6363",
    "targetType" : "entserver",
    "status" : "STOPPED"
  } ]
}
```

Any suggestions helpfull

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see your attempt to solve this problem, rather than write code for you. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(input)['result'].map do |h|
  [h['instanceName'], h['status']]
end.to_h
#⇒ {
#      "920_ENT_6017" => "RUNNING",
#      "920_JAS_8082" => "RUNNING",
#          "AIS_0005" => "RUNNING",
#  "DEN00KNL_DEP_920" => "RUNNING",
#           "ENT6547" => "STOPPED",
#         "HTML_8792" => "RUNNING",
#          "RTE_0004" => "RUNNING",
#           "ent4563" => "STOPPED",
#           "ent6021" => "RUNNING",
#       "ent6060_Win" => "RUNNING",
#           "ent6327" => "STOPPED",
#           "ent6363" => "STOPPED",
#            "ent790" => "STOPPED",
#           "ent7943" => "STOPPED",
#              "home" => "RUNNING",
#           "wls1213" => "RUNNING"
# }
```

Comment: can i print that output in table format with heading instance name and status

Comment: Yes  you definitely can.